# Permission Denied when trying to run knockpy.py in terminal ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to install and run `knockpy.py` but for some reason, each time I try to execute it, whether in sudo or not I get permission denied.

```sh
gp@ubuntu:~/knock/knockpy$ ./knockpy.py
bash: ./knockpy.py: Permission denied
```

I have installed knock from github already as you can see but still can not run the program. Am I doing something wrong? Please provide some assistance.

Comment: For a programming question, you'd have to extract and provide a [mcve]. I think you rather want to file a bug ticket. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Lastly, please check the description of tags before applying them, even if they are suggested to you.

Comment: Okay I will do that next time thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

To run a script on Linux, you need to either :

- ensure that the script is an executable. You can run `chmod a+x ./knockpy.py` in order to do so. Then call `./knockpy.py` to run the script.
- let the python interpreter execute the script by running the following command : `python ./knockpy.py`

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using the same suggestion you pointed out. The issue was i had to install python and python3 and then ran it.

python knockpy.py and then it worked, i had the same issue with sublist3r.